# how to config htaccess file after enabling mod_rewrite module?

Tags: 14.04, apache2, webserver, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I already install `apache2` then i enable the `mod_rewrite` module like this:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

after enabling i am confused about these lines, i can't understand what to do with them, as far as i know that what i have to do with these lines is that **" find the following section, and change the line that says AllowOverride from None to All. "**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

my problem is that I can't find a file with the above lines to edit.
I already looked in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`. In that directory, I only found two files:

```
000-default.conf 
default-ssl.conf
```

In both files i can't find above lines which i have to edit.

i edit the file  `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` in this directory but it still didn't worked at all.

i also looked in this `/etc/apache/sites-enabled/default.conf` directory but i can't find these lines in `dafault.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

i am working in `/var/www/html` directory then why it's giving me 403 forbidden error.

Still `.htaccess` is not running. It's giving me 403 forbidden error.

**here is the screen shot of folder permission:**

[image]

**here is the screen shot of 403 forbidden error:**
[image]

Comment: help me ...waiting for answers

Answer (score 6):

Edit `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` instead of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` and edit as instructed.

Here's mine:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: not worked. help me

Comment: It worked for me, dang updated ubuntu distros >.>

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, in Ubuntu 14.04 (and Apache 2.4) the default `DocumentRoot` was changed from `/var/www` to `/var/www/html`. Secondly, the configuration was considerably simplified, so those entries, while usually present by default, no longer appear in the new default site configuration.

Edit `/etc/apache/sites-enabled/default.conf`, and add these lines:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Your 403 Forbidden error is possibly because you are working in `/var/www` where you should be working in `/var/www/html`.

Finally, you shouldn't be enabling `All`, but pick out the options you need and enable [only those](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride).

Comment: cant find above line in default.conf

Comment: @jazz_razor You are supposed to *add* these lines, above the line with `</VirtualHost>`.

Comment: i added these lines but it still giving me 403 forbidden error

Comment: i am working in this directory /var/www/html/my_project

Comment: @jazz_razor I doubt your 403 error has anything to do with htaccess configuration. Have you set permissions correctly?

Comment: yes i set permissions correctly. in this `/var/www/html/` directory i can create folders, files and i can perform delete, edit actions easily through editor..

Comment: @jazz_razor yes, but are the permissions proper for Apache? Can the server read those files?

Comment: yes server can read those files.

Comment: if i change the pattern of url like this: `http://192.168.1.2/test.php` it runs the php code but when i switch url like this: `http://192.168.1.2/seocompany/` it gives me 403 forbidden error

Comment: @jazz_razor Did you restart apache after you did the modifications to the `000-default.conf` file? You can restart it with `sudo apache2ctl restart`. If you did, are you sure the rewrite rules are correct?

Comment: yes i restart the apache and my rewirte rules are correct because website is running live.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 14.04 (and Apache 2.4) the default DocumentRoot was changed from /var/www to /var/www/html.

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

add these lines at end

`<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>`

and of course >

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Changing the privileges of my .htaccess file to 755 seemed to work.

Comment: For security reason, other users may only read your .htaccess, you should use _sudo chmod 644 /var/www/html/.htaccess_  to update permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 (and Apache 2.4) the default `DocumentRoot` was changed from `/var/www` to `/var/www/html`.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

add these lines at end

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
```

and of course restart apache2 service

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```